# how to automatically make new file with mvim

Tags: vim, macvim

When I run `mvim .` it opens NERDTree but doesnt open a new file/buffer.

1. How might I accomplish this? Ideally when you type `mvim .` from terminal it would open MacVim, close NERDtree, and open a new buffer
2. I'm not sure if this is possible but is there a way that if I run `mvim .` from the command line multiple times it wouldn't open vim in a new window each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You are asking it to open your directory viewer, right? If not, why do you start vim passing the current directory (`.`) as argument? Leave it off and it will start with an empty buffer.

```
$ mvim
```

2.Take a look in the vim manual (`man vim`). You probably want the `--remote-silent` option.

```
$ mvim --remote-silent file
```

I personally use this so often that I've created an alias for it in my *.profile*:

```
alias v='mvim --remote-silent'
```

Comment: mainly so that when i open nerdtree its already in the correct project folder

Comment: @Tallboy, but when you start vim, it inherits the current directory, right? So you wouldn't need to give that argument

Answer (score 2):

As for your second question, vim allows you to send a file to an already running instance with `--remote` arguments, **if** vim is compiled with `+clientserver`. MacVim should be - if `:echo has("clientserver")` prints `1` in the command-line, then this should work. This will work for any vim compiled with `+clientserver`, including vim running within a terminal window.

When vim is using `clientserver` you can run mvim so that it sends the new file(s) to an already-running instance of vim, e.g.:

```
$ mvim --remote-silent file2.txt
```

Make an alias for `mvim` that always passes `--remote-silent`.

See `:help remote` for more details.